# Modifying Windows GUI objects from outside using handles

Tags: c++, winapi, reverse-engineering, automated-tests

Doing an automated testing application, I am looking for a way to modify Windows application GUI elements (labels, button texts, etc.) directly by accessing those elements from outside application. How can that be done if I know a windows/object handle (got it by Spy++) or when not, how would I search memory for strings or other values to be replaced?

Thank you.

Comment: If all you want to do is change the label of a control you can send it a `WM_SETTEXT` message.

Comment: And what about application internal values?
How does one send a message to other process handle item? How do I know if it is a label, edit box... detect type and cast it somehow?

Answer (score 3):

[UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) is a much better way of doing what you're trying to do.  It even works on custom controls (that implement UI Automation), windowless controls, and so forth.

Comment: That is not exactly appropriate for my requirements. I need to be able to force certain values to fake situations unless other actions meet certain criteria. For example: I want to be able to force info in a GPU-Z application that resembles multiple models of GPUs. A user being tested needs to visually be able to tell if some data is wrong and not matching. I can't afford to remake GUIs of each of such apps. So the idea is to run a service/app that will loop and maintain fake values...

Comment: Now, when I've put it this way... imagine it as a game trainer and I need to force a value of a certain variable in that "game". How do I search for (I guess?) memory address of the first char in array and force my data into it in a loop that would be faster than game refresh loop (every 10ms, every 1ms...)?

Comment: @user2956864 then you're not *testing*, you're (at best) mocking.  It's going to be very application-specific.

Comment: @user I don't see how your requirement cannot be achieved using UI Automation. You added a new requirement (directly accessing the memory locations of variables) but fail to provide a rationale why this is necessary, or how this adds anything on top of using UI Automation. Now if you **really** want to find the address of a window's text, this information is available through it's `HWND`. If you are willing to write a module that can access kernel memory.